# How do you get db2 clidriver license db2consv_t.lic?

Tags: db2, db2-zos

I cannot find the db2consv_t.lic.
How can i download it ?

I downloaded the cli driver v11.5.9_linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar from ibm i fixcentral and extrated it.

Under the readme instructions there is:
5. To connect to DB2 for z/OS Server,download the license file db2consv_t.lic and copy to the license folder.

```
      $HOME/db2_cli_odbc_driver/odbc_cli/clidriver/license
```

Comment: Could you add what you want to connect (example: client on Linux to server on z/OS)? What license do you have? For z/OS you typically need to buy a license.

Comment: Ask your "IBM site coordinator"  to give you the license file (via download), or to buy one (IBM Db2 connect personal edition license). If you have a Db2-connect *SERVER* then you don't need a license file as you can connect indirectly via that server. If you are connecting to Z/OS your DBA can also configure the target system for db2connectactivate (server side licensing, instead of client side licensing).  So it's necessary to know __exactly__ what options are available to you , and that is site specific information. Not a question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
The db2consv_t.lic ist a test license which you can get if you download Db2:
https://www.ibm.com/products/db2